# How to configure Webpack to load a module from its src folder instead of dist?

Tags: typescript, webpack, package.json, lerna, monorepo

I am working on a monorepo and therefore I want Webpack to load my sources from `src` instead of `dist` (`dist` is specified in `package.json`).

For example given the following structure:

```
/packages/core/dist/index.js (compiled output)
/packages/core/src/index.ts (original TypeScript source)
/packages/core/package.json (`main` and `module` point to `dist`)
```

Now inside `/packages/foo/src/index.ts` I am doing `import Foo from '@test/core'`. The problem is that Webpack reads `core` package's `package.json` and uses its `module` and `main` fields that point to `dist` folder. I instead want Webpack to load the original sources from `src`, because this `@test/core` is part of my own codebase and not an external dependency.

Is there a way to force Webpack to load my original TS sources only for certain modules like the ones beginning with `@test/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [resolve alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/).

For example, assuming your webpack config is above the packages folder:

```
{
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".json"],
    alias: {
      "@test/core": path.resolve(__dirname, "packages/core/src")
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use require as usual, but any paths starting with `@test/core` will be resolved to `path.resolve(__dirname, "packages/core/dist")`.

- `require("@test/core")` => `packages/core/src/index.ts`
- `require("@test/core/module")` => `packages/core/src/module.ts`

As `.ts` is a non-standard extension you have to add this to `resolve.extensions`.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it with `NormalModuleReplacementPlugin`:

I put this in my Webpack config:

```
 plugins: [
    new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
      /@test\/[a-z]+$/,
      resource => {
        resource.request = resource.request + '/src/index'
      }
    )
 ]
```

Since I am using TS, I also had to add `.ts` extension to:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx']
}
```

Now importing `@test/xyz` will be imported as `@test/xyz/src/index` -- and it will first look out for `.ts` extension.